# What happens after creating PCA?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pca

What happens after I create a dimensionality reduction algorithm (PCA) that has produced a matrix W?
How do I now use it to predict real time data?
Do I need to create a User interface or what?
If thats the case, how and where?
Im completely lost

Comment: You should probably look at some kind of method to actually identify based on the PCA, like a k-nearest neighbours. Then you use your PCA object to transform incoming data and then the result (usually the first or second PC, depending on the contribution to variability) goes into your k-NN to give your predictions

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you wanted to achieve by doing PCA. One use case can be Clustering. If you just look at the summary of your PCA model you'll be able to see the list of Principal Components and the Proportion of variance explained by each Principal Component. You can choose components which explain most of the variance (normally the cumulative proportion of variance explained by PCs should be >80%) in your model. You can plot a Scree plot and look for break in the graph to determine number of Components to use in Clustering. Input those PCs in your clustering model and you might see some good clustering results.

For your second query follow this [Link](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/practical-guide-principal-component-analysis-python/)

And you don't need to create any user interface right now. Just follow the above link and you should get some understanding around PCA and as to how to use it for predictive modeling.